# Normal sequence

Tags: measure-theory

I have trouble in understanding this definition: "Let P be a cube in $\mathbb{R^n} $ such that $ P =[a_1,b_1] \times ... \times [a_n,b_n] $
. Let $ \Pi_k , k \in \mathbb{N} $ be a sequence of cube P partitions. We define cube P partitions as finite family of cubes $ \Pi = {P_1,...,P_m} $ such that $ P_1 \cup ... \cup P_m = P $  $int P_j \cap intP_i = \emptyset, i \neq j $. We will say, that $ \Pi_k $ is a normal sequence if $ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}diam( \Pi_k ) = 0 $. $ diam(\Pi) = max(diam(P1),...,diam(P_m)) $, where $diam(P_j) $ is just a volume of some cube " I do not understand how finite family of cubes for every partition of the cube P can achieve 0.

Comment: limits don't need to be attained

Comment: with this what i understand $ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}diam( \Pi_k ) = 0 $ this means that taking infinity many finite partitions of cube we will get 0 how and can u give me some example ?

Comment: There is a sequence of partitions.  As $k$ increases, the partition $\Pi_k$ has "smaller" parts.

Comment: i mean taking infinity many partitions which contain finite family of cube

Comment: Why is that so?

Comment: i mean for every $ \Pi_j  $ we have to take $P_1,..,P_m$ such that$ P = P_1,...,P_m$

Comment: okay now i think i understand this definition, but could you give me some example, please ?

Comment: That's like the diet advice, eat more often but analogical smaller portions, or best: _continously nothing_. (Could not resist to tell this joke.)